# Object in class with interdependence

Tags: c++

I am facing an issue with the creation of an object inside a class `A` which needs `A` to be constructed.

I am getting an incomplete type error

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class B;

class typeOne;


class A
{
    B<typeOne> myObj;
    
    public: 
    int myNumber = 10;
    int myNumberTwo = 20;

    A():
    myObj(*this)
    {}
};

class typeOne
{
    int number_;

    public:
    typeOne (const A& myA)
    : number_(myA.myNumber)
    {}

    int number()
    {
        return number_;
    }
};

class typeTwo
{
    int number_;

    public:
    typeTwo (const A& myA)
    : number_(myA.myNumberTwo)
    {}

    int number()
    {
        return number_;
    }
};


template<typename T>
class B
:
public T
{
    const A& myA_;
    std::vector<int> myVec_;

    public:

    explicit B(const A& myA)
            : 
            T(myA),
            myA_(myA),
            myVec_(this->number())
            {}
};


int main() {

    A obj1;

    B<typeOne> obj2(obj1);

    B<typeTwo> obj3(obj1);

    std::cout << "here" << std::endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Currently, this is giving me an error.
How can I create `myObj` inside class `A`?
Should I use a smart pointer so that I can use an incomplete type. Initialize the pointer to `nullptr`and after constructing the class `A` use  `myObj = std::make_shared<B<typeOne>>(*this);` to construct `myObj`?

Kind regards

Comment: mutual dependency is often a design issue rather than something that needs to be fixed by rearranging the code.

Comment: why is the relation between your classes like it is? Why does `B` need a const reference to an `A`  as member?

Comment: `B` will require a function of `A`. Also with the reference, I guarantee that A must be created in order to create `B`

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is splitting the implementations of `typeOne` and `typeTwo` from their class definitions. Now, you only need a forward declaration of `A` for the class definitions to compile.

This means, we can reorder them like this:

- forward declaration of `A`
- class definitions of `typeOne` and `typeTwo`
- template class definition of `B`
- class definition of `A`
- implementation of `typeOne` and `typeTwo` methods

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/7MePoffx4)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A;

class typeOne
{
    int number_;
public:
    typeOne(const A& myA);
    int number() { return number_; }
};

class typeTwo
{
    int number_;
public:
    typeTwo (const A& myA);
    int number() { return number_; }
};

template<typename T>
class B : public T
{
    const A& myA_;
    std::vector<int> myVec_;
public:
    explicit B(const A& myA) :
        T(myA),
        myA_(myA),
        myVec_(this->number())
        {}
};

class A
{
    B<typeOne> myObj;
public: 
    int myNumber = 10;
    int myNumberTwo = 20;

    A() :
        myObj(*this)
        {}
};


typeOne::typeOne (const A& myA)
    : number_(myA.myNumber)
    {}

typeTwo::typeTwo (const A& myA)
    : number_(myA.myNumberTwo)
    {}


int main() {
    A obj1;
    B<typeOne> obj2(obj1);
    B<typeTwo> obj3(obj1);
    std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion.

I was able to do something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/65rG164eW
I think it is also a possible solution

Comment: Would it also be a good solution?